# Running gtkmm inside Docker for Mac : Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

Tags: macos, docker, x11, gtkmm

Excuse me.
I try to run code using gtkmm-2.4 inside a docker for Mac. I tried it with refer to this site.(https://fredrikaverpil.github.io/2016/07/31/docker-for-mac-and-gui-applications/)

I see the following error:

Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 192.168.1.11:0

Dockerfile

```
FROM debian

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    automake \
    build-essential \
    dpkg-sig \
    libgtkmm-2.4-dev \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# cleanup
RUN apt-get -qy autoremove
```

setting:

```
ip=$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | awk '$1=="inet" {print $2}')
xhost + $ip
```

docker run:

```
docker run --rm -e DISPLAY=$ip:0 \
-it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix my_image /bin/bash
```

and the error in docker:

```
g++ GtkmmTest.cpp -o GtkmmTest `pkg-config gtkmm-2.4 --cflags --libs`
./GtkmmTest

(GtkmmTest:607): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: 192.168.1.11:0

echo $DISPLAY
192.168.1.11:0
```

I thank you in advance for your reply.

Comment: Your Docker for Mac runs a VM which has no Display as such. Even if you try and share the Display with the container, the VM itself has no Display. So this is not going to work. You need to install a separate ubuntu or centos 7 VM with display and do this. Or you would need to XVFB inside the container and use that for display

Comment: I can't thank you enough.
When I tried this site,http://fabiorehm.com/blog/2014/09/11/running-gui-apps-with-docker/, firefox was displayed using xquartz.
I thought it was strange, I rebuilt the above Dockerfile and it worked